# Access modifier Protected

Tags: java, protected, access-modifiers

```
package my.examples.javaexam;

import accessTest.*;

public class DiffPackageSubClass extends Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t1 = new Test();
        System.out.println(t1.a);
        t1.display();

    }
}

package accessTest;

public class Test {
    public int a = 10;
    protected int b = 120;
    protected void display(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
    int c = 130;
    private int d = 999;
}
```

Hello.

I am trying to figure how Access modifier 'Protected' works.

I've created two packages 'my.examples.javaexam' and 'accessTest'

As far as I know, you can use protected variables or methods if the class is in different package but is a sub class.

So I made DiffPackageSubClass class in different package but made it inherit Test Class in accessTest package.

However, when I try to execute the code it gives me an error saying that the t1.display(); can not be excuted as 'display()' has protected access in 'accessTest.Test'

I am unsure where did I go wrong with the code :(

I've been staring at the code for a while but still couldn't figure out why it gives me an error.

please help me to understand this

Comment: Hint: all such basic things have been asked here many many times. They are also documented in any good book or tutorial. And: you are expected to do a bit of research prior posting a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/access-modifiers-java/ use

```
//Java program to illustrate 
//protected modifier 
package p2; 
import p1.*; //importing all classes in package p1 

//Class B is subclass of A 
class B extends A 
{   
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        B obj = new B(); 
        obj.display(); 
    }  

} 

//Java program to illustrate 
//protected modifier 
package p1; 

//Class A 
public class A 
{ 
    protected void display() 
    { 
       System.out.println("Test"); 
    } 
}
```

i.e you need to instantiate with **DiffPackageSubClass** class in main because protected has access in different package through subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2) says:

> Details on protected Access
>
> A protected member or constructor of an object may be accessed from outside the package in which it is declared only by code that is responsible for the implementation **of that object**.

(emphasis mine)

The main method doesn't define the implementation of an *object* of type `DiffPackageSubClass`.

In short, you can access `this.a` and `this.display` in instance methods of the subclass. But not the protected members of another object of type `Test`.

More details follow in the specification. This is the official point of truth. In particular, it says:

> Let C be the class in which a protected member is declared. Access is permitted only within the body of a subclass S of C.
>
> In addition, if Id denotes an instance field or instance method, then:
>
> If the access is by a qualified name Q.Id or a method reference expression Q :: Id (§15.13), where Q is an ExpressionName, then the access is permitted if and only if the type of the expression Q is S or a subclass of S.

So, in your example, the main method could access `t1.a` and `t1.display` if t1 was declared (and was an instance of) `DiffPackageSubClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Protected means that the method\variable is visible within the same package. 
An its is visible from the class that **extends** your class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

So that the display() method becames the member of DiffPackageSubClass  automatically and you can use it like this:

```
new DiffPackageSubClass().display();
```

but still you have to call the method of subclass, not superclass.

```
new Test().display()
```

is still accessible within the `accessTest` package only

Answer (score 0):

It should be access from the inherited object, not as a normal object. see example below:

```
public class DiffPackageSubClass extends Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t1 = new Test();
        System.out.println(t1.a);
        t1.display(); // error
        DiffPackageSubClass diffPackageSubClass = new DiffPackageSubClass();
        diffPackageSubClass.display(); // ok 

    }
}
```